# An electron, moving south, enters a magnetic field. Because of this field, the electron curves upward. We may conclude that the magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

An electron, moving south, enters a magnetic field. Because of this field, the electron curves upward. We may conclude that the magnetic field must have a component:

a. towards the east.
b. towards the west.
c. downward.
d. upward.
e. towards the north.

The answer is "towards the west". I am very confused by this question and I think I am misunderstanding how to orient my fingers for this. What I interpreted as the electron moving south would mean that my index finger points vertically downwards and therefore my thumb (force) would be pointing into the page/and middle finger (magnetic field component) points to the left. Since this is an electron, this would be flipped so my answer was "towards the east" for the magnetic field component. But I guess you could also have the index finger pointing vertically downwards with the thumb coming out of the page and magnetic field pointing right/east, flip it since it's an electron, and then it would be west. Is that the correct reasoning? And how do you know that it is this latter reasoning to use (since there are two ways magnetic field can be oriented when the index finger/velocity is pointing down?)?

Am I misunderstanding North/South, is that not the same thing as vertically up or down? Does that mean into or out of the page and if so, which one is which?

Comment: North, south, east, and west are all horizontal. All of those are perpendicular to up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have the right general idea.  The main clue is that the electron curves upward.  In other words, it is experiencing a force "out of the page."  So, by the method you are using, the right hand thumb points out of the page (up force), the index finger points down the page (south velocity), and the middle finger point to the right (B-field direction assuming positive charge).  However, since the charge of the electron is negative, you reverse the direction of the B-field for a final answer of to the left or west.

I hope this helps.